# find point and size in scaled and rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, vector, trigonometry

I have a rectangle 1: green, with the following properties:

```
x: 102, y: 121, width: 900, height: 900
```

and I have a child rectangle within it, red (properties related to green 1):

```
x: 327, y: 415, width: 271, height: 183
```

- If I scale down green by 0.75 and rotate it 30deg, the same will be applied to its child.

How do I calculate the **size and position of the red child (in grey)** *whist inside a scaled and rotated green*, **to be the same as non rotated/scaled red?**

http://codepen.io/christianpugliese/pen/RWWdvN?editors=001

[image]

Comment: Do you need position in rotated coordinate system? If yes, just multiply all values by scale.

Comment: Where is the center of rotation and enlargement for the green rectangle, is it rotated about its center?

Comment: @MBo, already tried that, multiply works for size only, not for position

Comment: @Salixalba, yes, on its center

Comment: I have it on a codepen: http://codepen.io/christianpugliese/pen/RWWdvN?editors=001

Answer (score 0):

Lets make this a bit more mathematical. We have a Green square with coords

```
g = {(102,121),(1002,121),(1002,1021),(102,1021)}
```

and Red rectangle with coord

```
r={{327,415),(498,415),(498,598),(327,598)}.
```

the centre of G is (552,571).

Let T be the translation from the centre to the origin. S be the scalling by 0.75 about the origin, and R the rotation by 30º. In matrix terms

```
T = (-552)
    (-571)

S = (0.75, 0   )
    (0   , 0.75)

R = (cos 30, -sin 30)
    (sin 30,  cos 30)
```

The complete tranformation to a point p = (x,y) is

```
T' R S T' p

= T' R S (x-552, y-571)

= T' R (0.75*(x-552), 0.75*(y-571))

= T' (cos 30 * (0.75*(x-552) -sin 30 * 0.75*(y-571))
     (sin 30 * (0.75*(x-552) +cos 30 * 0.75*(y-571))

= ( cos 30 * (0.75*(x-552) -sin 30 * 0.75*(y-571) + 552 )
  (sin 30 * (0.75*(x-552) +cos 30 * 0.75*(y-571) + 571  )
```

If we let the rectangle have border xl, xh, yl, yh, the corners are (xl,yl), ... (xh,yh). We apply the transfomation to each corner, Giving point A=(ax,ay), B, C, D. We need to ensure each point is inside the rectangle,so xl <= ah << xh.

This gives a set of equations to solve. Which should be doable.